# Area between $x=y^2-7$ and $x=e^y$ for $-1\leq y\leq 1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area, multiple-integral

I need to find the area of the shaded region here

[image]

I thought the area would be $\int_{-1}^{1}{y^2-7-e^y}dy$,which got me $-\frac{40}{3}-3+\frac1e$, but I was marked wrong.

By inspection it looks like the area under the blue curve has a symmetry that makes its total area $0$ from $x=-7$ to $x=\frac12$. So I figured the area I'm looking for is the area under the red curve from $x=1/2$ to $x=3$. I tried this and got an answer of $\frac13 - 2$ which was also marked wrong.

What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the red curve is on the right and the blue is on the left. so the resulting area would be
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \left(e^y - \left(y^2-7\right) \right)dy
$$
and if you did the calculations correctly, you would negate your first answer...

As [Namburu Karthik](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/790224/namburu-karthik) points out below, you did make an arithmetic mistake evaluating the integral, which you can check at [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5Be%5Ey-%28y%5E2-7%29%2C+%7By%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D)

Comment: Ya he wrote 3 instead of e

Comment: @NamburuKarthik +1, updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is wrong. You got a negative number!

Not that $y$ can take any value from $-1$ to $1$ and that, for each $y\in[-1,1]$, $x$ tan take any values from $y^2-7$ up to $e^y$. So, the area is equal to$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{y^2-t}^{e^y}1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy=\int_{-1}^1e^y-(y^2-t)\,\mathrm dy.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider interchanging axes that is easier to evaluate

$$\int_{-1}^1 \left[ e^x -\left(x^2-7\right)\right] dx $$

Comment: +1, You likely mean to integrate from $-1$, made the change for you

Comment: Thanks for it !